# ursina fps controller wont jump if i press shift and ctrl

Tags: frame-rate, ursina

I was creating a game in ursina using the FirstPersonController import to use as the player. There's just an issue when I hold shift/Ctrl then press space to jump, The player doesn't jump.
I have looked through the FPS controller code but nothing seems to contribute to the issue.

I don't think showing my code here will help as its an imports code.
Any help or info is well appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has been fixed. It was a bug with input in general, not the FirstPersonController specifically. Try updating ursina with:

`pip install https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/archive/master.zip --upgrade --force-reinstall`

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to fix the issue. All up an running perfectly now